# order post according to custom array position

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to list of post according to custom filed.

Here i have 9 post with different 3 position (middle, top, bottom)

```
Post ID    title      position
1          Post1      Top
2          Post2      Bottom 
3          Post3      Top
4          Post4      Bottom 
5          Post5      Middle
6          Post6      Bottom 
7          Post7      Top
8          Post8      Bottom 
9          Post9      Top
10         Post10     Middle
```

Now i want to get post according like this order

```
5          Post5      Middle
2          Post2      Bottom 
1          Post1      Top
10         Post10     Middle
4          Post4      Bottom
3          Post3      Top
6          Post6      Bottom
7          Post7      Top
8          Post8      Bottom
9          Post9      Top
```

So first came middle,bottom,top so i want post order like this one, middle,bottom and top. I do not want complete middle position and then bottom and then top.

I like to list get first 3 post of middle,bottom, top.I need this listing wordpress, can any one know, how can i do this task

Thanks
CSR

Comment: Sorry, my table structure is diffrent, it is like this

Wp_posts:
Post ID    title     
1          Post1     
2          Post2      
3          Post3     
4          Post4      
5          Post5     
6          Post6      
7          Post7     
8          Post8      
9          Post9      
10        Post10

And another table is

wp_postmeta

meta_id       post_id       meta_key   meta_value
1             Post5          Middle     Middle
2             Post2          Bottom     Bottom
3             Post1          Top  Top
4     post10  Middle      Middle
5
6
7
8
9
10

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like the following:

```sql
SELECT PostID, title, position
FROM (
   SELECT PostID, title, position,
          @grp := IF(@pos = position, @grp + 1,
                     IF(@pos := position, 1, 1)) AS grp
   FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @grp := 0, @pos := '') AS vars
   ORDER BY position, title) AS t
ORDER BY grp, FIELD(position, 'Middle', 'Bottom', 'Top')
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b088a9/5)

Comment: Why do you use `titile` but not `PostID` here - `ORDER BY position, title` ?

Comment: Sorry, my table structure is diffrent, it is like this

Wp_posts:
Post ID    title     
1          Post1     
2          Post2      
3          Post3     
4          Post4      
5          Post5     
6          Post6      
7          Post7     
8          Post8      
9          Post9      
10        Post10

And another table is

wp_postmeta

meta_id       post_id       meta_key   meta_value
1             Post5          Middle     Middle
2             Post2          Bottom     Bottom
3             Post1          Top  Top
4     post10  Middle      Middle
5
6
7
8
9
10

Comment: @csr My answer addresses the OP. Try to adjust the query to suit your actual needs.

Comment: http://fineco.gogoody.in/index.php/projects/, when i run this query, it show blank array